# Comments moved to chat, link is 404

Tags: support, comments, specific-answer

I wanted to read the comments of [this answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/117206/how-do-i-deal-with-an-autistic-employee-who-criticizes-teammates-publicly-and-do/117221#117221). One of them, from a mod, says:

> Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81371/discussion-on-answer-by-richard-u-how-would-you-deal-with-autistic-employee-who)

But the link points to 404 Not Found page.

Is it fixable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The chatroom was automatically deleted for inactivity, which happens when a chatroom has less then 15 messages total or messages only by one user after 7 days of the last message.

To view deleted chatrooms you need 10.000 reputation combined network wide (outside of SO and meta.SE).

I made a screenshot for you so you can read the comments still:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Chatrooms are normally depreciated (deleted) when they're inactive for a period of time.  The one you're trying to access hasn't seen any discussion since last August, and has less than 15 messages, so has been routinely deleted.

Normally, comments are moved to chat when there's 20 or more comments, so the chatrooms are frozen, and remain visible.  There are times when the comments are overly chatty or divert from the answer/question so are moved earlier.  This is rare, however.

Deleted chatrooms are visible to users with over 10K rep points.

See this Meta link

[Are chat rooms hard-deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/321066/are-chat-rooms-hard-deleted)

For more information on this.